# Count how often a row contains a keyword

Tags: mysql, coldfusion

What is the most efficient way to count in how many rows each keyword is present. For example given the following list:

```
cat, dog, basement, parrot, whale, dolphins
```

And given the following simple database:

```
ID  TEXTDATA
1   The cat is in the basement, the cat is not on the roof.
2   The dog is going home.
3   The birds are flying in the sky.
4   The dolphins are swimming in the ocean, i really like dolphins.
5   The mouse live in the basement.
```

The results should be:

```
cat=1 ( two occurrences in one row )
dog=1 ( one occurrence in one row )
basement=2 ( two occurrences in two rows )
parrot=0 ( zero occurrences )
whale=0 ( zero occurrences )
dolphins=1 ( two occurrence in one row )
```

The results may be computed in coldfusion or mysql whichever is more efficient.

Comment: See REPLACE(). Compare the length of the string with the length of the string minus the needle.

Comment: As far as i know this function is ussually used when trying to count one specific word or substring. I am trying to count multiple keywords, if possible without have to recompute for each individual keyword.

Comment: What's inefficient? SQL isn't great for this sort of thing, so if you want to use it, you may just have to accept its limitations.

Comment: BTW, I think you meant 'count how many rows each of the following keyords appears within'

Comment: Efficiency is important because this query should run about 40.000 times a day. The solution mentioned ealier is not scaleable, Even with just a couple of keywords it could become very slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try nested loops.

```
<cfset wordCount = ArrayNew(2)>
<cfset arrayRow = 0>
<cfset words = "cat,dog,etc">
<cfloop list = "#words# index = "thisWord">
<cfset arrayRow ++>
<cfset wordCount[arrayRow][1] = thisWord>
<cfset wordCount[arrayRow[2] = 0>

<cfloop query = "yourQuery">
<cfif listfind(textdata, thisWord, " "> <!--- space delimited --->
<cfset wordCount[arrayRow[2] += 1>
closing tags
```

Comment: This works surprisingly fast. Even when i use refind instead of find the performance is very acceptable. Another bonus is i can break the loop if an x number of occurences has been counted. This is between 25% till 400% faster then mutliple simple select count(id) from ... where data like '%dog%')

Comment: @Nebu - Perhaps on a small scale, but it is not feasible for large data sets.  Wildcard searches are almost always among the slowest slow. However, do not just consider execution time. Use [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html) to understand and compare the different options: LIKE, MATCH, FULLTEXT, etcetera...

Comment: For large data sets, I think whatever gets tried will be slow.

Comment: Well the idea is to try and avoid having a large data set in the first place ;-) LIKE is never going to be a speed demon (especially multiple LIKE operations). However, neither is pulling a huge query across the network and looping a x thousand times. This sounds like the type of task designed for FULLTEXT, MATCH, etcetera. I would look into those options and compare the performance with EXPLAIN. With the proper indexes, fulltext should perform better than a plain vanilla LIKE.

Comment: @DanBracuk You are right. Fortunately in my situation the number or records that need to be processed is very small <1000. I tried different solutions and the speed various from 30 milliseconds (this solution) up to 1 second (Strawberry's solution).

Comment: Doesn't this rely on the word being mid-sentence?

Comment: @Strawberry Yes, my implementation contains <cfif refind('\b#thisWord#\b',textdata) gt 0> instead of <cfif listfind(textdata, thisWord, " "> to solve this.

Comment: @Strawberry, this does not rely on the word being mid-sentence.  This:  `phrase = "cat dog";
writeoutput(listfind(phrase, "cat", " "));` returns 1.

Comment: @DanBracuk Try this phrase     phrase = "This is a very little cat.";  then    writeoutput(listfind(phrase, "cat", " ")); returns 0.

Comment: That's because of a period at the end of the sentence.  @Sung's answer addresses that issue, which is why I voted it up.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT x.keyword
     , SUM(textdata RLIKE CONCAT('[[:<:]]',CAST(x.keyword AS CHAR CHARACTER SET utf8),'[[:>:]]')) cnt FROM my_table
JOIN (
SELECT 'cat' keyword
 UNION
SELECT 'dog'
 UNION
SELECT 'basement'
 UNION
SELECT 'parrot'
 UNION
SELECT 'whale'
 UNION
SELECT 'dolphins'
) x 
GROUP BY keyword;
```

Comment: This approach is new to me and i like the idea. I tested this against my database and unfortunatly it is rather slow. Compared to a simple select (select count(id) from ... where data like '%dog%') as a0,(select count(id) from ... where data like '%cat%') as a2, this method is about 4 times slower.

Comment: OK. But it has the advantage of returning the correct answer.

Comment: Yes that's a big plus. Still speed is very important and unfortunately this solution is just to slow.

Comment: Well, perhaps explore FULLTEXT indexes.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I simulated the dataset via QuerySim (http://cflib.org/udf/QuerySim).

```
<cfscript>
data = querySim('
ID , TEXTDATA
1|The cat is in the basement, the cat is not on the roof.
2|The dog is going home.
3|The birds are flying in the sky.
4|The dolphins are swimming in the ocean, i really like dolphins.
5|The mouse live in the basement.
');
</cfscript>
```

A nice data dump to verify.

```
<cfdump var="#data#">
```

And a pair of loops.

```
<cfloop list="cat,dog,basement,parrot,whale,dolphins" index="i" >
    <cfset count = 0>
    <cfloop query="data" >
        <cfif ListFind(REReplaceNoCase(TEXTDATA, '[^a-z0-9]', ' ', 'all'), variables.i, " ")>
            <cfset count++>
        </cfif>
    </cfloop>
    <cfoutput>#variables.i#=#variables.count#</cfoutput><br>
</cfloop>
```

Is it the most efficient?  Not sure.  I just wrapped another CFLOOP and looped it 10000 times:

{ts '2016-06-20 10:21:35'}
{ts '2016-06-20 10:21:44'}

Nine seconds.

Comment: Besides some small alterations this solution is very similar to Dan Bracuk solution.

Comment: Yup, very similar.  The only main difference is taking account of commas and periods with the REReplaceNoCase -- when I ran it without that, I noticed that "basement," and "basement." were not being included.  Either way, glad you found a solution that works for you!

Comment: plus 1 for the commas and periods.